# Shows only default page in ubuntu using valet-linux

Tags: linux, laravel, ubuntu, valet

I installed valet-linux in kubuntu 18.04 and followed the documentation. I also changed the path to make **valet** command works. I also added the directory of my projects which is located in another partition using  **valet park** and change its port to 8888 so it won't have conflict with   apache which listens to port 80.

But when I run *my-laravel-project.test* it shows the Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page not my laravel project page which when I tested it using **php artisan serve**, it is working. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I experienced the same.

Can you check if valet is running correctly?

```
valet status
```

In my case it looked like this:

```
Php7.2-fpm is running...
Nginx is stopped...
```

So I fixed it by stopping, apache since it was obviously interfering with valet:

```
sudo service apache2 stop
```

I checked the status again

```
valet status
```

and now it looked fine:

```
Php7.2-fpm is running...
Nginx is running...
```

Now Valet worked for me on Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm running XAMPP, and after trying `service apache2 stop` the problem persisted.  I had to go to the XAMPP GUI and stop Apache from there.  After that, then I was able to `service nginx start` successfully. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

add `DirectoryIndex index.php` to your apache config